# Deleting duplicate videos

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-php-client

We have roughly 28,000 failed uploads in our YouTube account because they are all duplicates with the [Upload failed: Duplicate upload](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/58139?hl=en) message.  Whenever I attempt to remove these using the YouTube Data API, it returns the following message for each: [The video that you are trying to delete cannot be found. Check the value of the request's id parameter to ensure that it is correct](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete#errors).

We have the video ids listed in our database and they correspond to the videos marked as duplicates.  How can I delete these without having to manually go through and delete them 30 at a time through the Creator Studio?

Comment: Try this solution if it will work in your case. Based on this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/ay8cZZ1PmmI), they delete the duplicate videos by following these steps.

1. Make sure none of your videos in playlist appear in favourites. (after u add to playlist from favourites, remove from favourites)
2. Now, select all videos in playlist and move them to favorites.(this eliminates duplicates automatically)
3. Remove those videos from playlist
4. Move videos back from favourites to playlist

Comment: If this will not work on you, then I think there is no other way to delete it. Since you already know the `videoID`, then it will be easy for you to delete it using the [Videos: delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete).

Comment: I've tried to use the [Videos: delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete) tool, but it comes back with a 404.

I tried the first approach, but after taking a closer look at the discussion, it seems to only modify playlists, not actual videos.